# How to create PDO insert statement from looped key and value array

Tags: php, arrays, sqlite, pdo

From `POST` method like `$uri = explode("&", $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);` I can retrieve the value that I need for the insertion operation. Also I have a constructor function that calls another function that returns `PDO` for my sqlite connection:

```
 private function dbConnect()
{
    try {
        $this->db = new PDO('sqlite:model.sqlite3');
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $this->db;

}
```

This method has been tested with `GET` and is ok. Now I want to insert into table new record by URI Calls:

```
private function disciplines(){
        // Cross validation if the request method is POST else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
        if($this->get_request_method() != "PUT"){
            $this->response('',406);
        }
        $uri= array();
        //echo "The query string is: ".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 
        $uri = explode("&", $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
        if(uri){  

        $sTable= array();
        $sValue= array();
        foreach ($uri as $var_val) {
        $var_val = explode('=', $var_val);
        $var[]= $var_val[0];
        $val[]= $var_val[1];

        }

        array_shift($var);
        array_shift($val);
        //shift arry is for esclude first element on arrays
        $sTable= implode(',', $var);
        $sValue= implode(',', $val);

        print_r(array_values($var));
        print_r(array_values($val));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 Array //array1
(
    [0] => discipline
    [1] => Material
)
Array // array 2
(
    [0] => sword
    [1] => Iron
)
```

**Final desire step:**

```
$qry = $this->db->exec(
        'INSERT INTO disciplines ($sTable) VALUES ($sValue)');
        echo $qry;
```

Does not work! Please can you put me in right direction? Any help is valued.

What I get now:

```
 echo $qry;
 'INSERT INTO discipline (Array) VALUES (Array)');
```

What I need:

```
 INSERT INTO disciplines (discipline, material ) VALUES (sword, iron )');
```

Comment: You need use `implode()`to get the plain text from an array

Comment: You can use `parse_str()` on the query string to automatically parse the query string instead of making your own. http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: rray thanks, but i did:
   $sTable= implode(',', $var);
   $sValue= implode(',', $val);

Comment: You expect the uri to contain field names and values, but what if it contains [malicious sql commands instead](http://bobby-tables.com/)?  Use PDO parameters!

Comment: James. PDO parameter and Binding_param was the pattern. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the arrays are validated properly

```
<?php

$sql = 'INSERT INTO disciplines ( ' . implode( ',', $arr1 ) . ' ) VALUES ( ' . implode( ',', $arr2 ) . ' )';

?>
```

But i would recommend using prepared statements with placeholders

```
<?php

$sql = 'INSERT INTO disciplines ( ' . implode( ',', $arr1 ) . ' ) VALUES ( ' . implode( ',', array_fill( 0, count( $arr2 ), '?' ) ) . ' )';

?>
```

Have a look at prepare() and exec()
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Hi Tom, first and second examples produce a syntax error. I came from obj-c typed coding and I struggle a bit with the syntax of php. Can you check?

Comment: Sorry, im on a small screen and its easy to miss things when writing code directly inside editor here. Fixed some missing ")" on implode()

Comment: You're gonna need single quotes around each array item.

Comment: Yea, thats true in the first example - unless its integer. Go for the prepared statements example ( last example )

Comment: thank you all for precious help. I have a sub question: it's possible to implode an array outside of the query?

Comment: Ofcourse, just implode it: $imploded = implode( ',', $arr ); http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php